# How to fetch job_id of BigQueryOperator in downstream task

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

we are calling BigQueryOperator to execute the few sqls in loop. its working fine but we need the job_id of that BigQueryOperator (generated in each iteration) in downstream task to fetch metadata data from backend tables. is there any way to do it?

```
def run_1(**kwargs):
    val=kwargs["task_instance"].xcom_pull(task_ids='my_ip', key='ce')
    skl=kwargs["task_instance"].xcom_pull(task_ids='my_ip', key='st')
    tt = len(val['q'])
    task_list = []
    task=[]
    job_ids={}
    for recon_key in range(0,tt):
        v_task=skl[recon_key].strip()  + "_se"
        bq_operator = BigQueryOperator(sql=val['sq'][recon_key],
                                               task_id=v_task,
                                               dag=dag,
                                               use_legacy_sql=False, )

run_sourc = PythonOperator(task_id='run', provide_context=True,
                                    python_callable=run_1, dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version you're running on, but I checked the code on Airflow main branch, where the `BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator` (the name for `BigQueryOperator` since Airflow 2.0) pushes the job_id to XCom, with a key "job_id". This means you can pull the job id from XCom in the downstream task:

```py
bq_operator = BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(task_id="bq_task", ...)

def do_something(**context):
    job_id = context["task_instance"].xcom_pull(task_ids="bq_task", key="job_id")
    # and do something with job_id...

run_sourc = PythonOperator(task_id="run", python_callable=do_something, ...)

bq_operator >> run_sourc
```

Comment: i am using 1.10.15  and its not giving this in UI. is there any alternative approach

Comment: In 1.10.15, the job_id is already written to XCom: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.15/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py#L306. XComs can be found in the UI under Admin -> XComs.

Comment: is there any way to achieve same in BigQueryInsertJobOperator